# Change flex direction to column when height of another div changes or performs a wrap of it's contents

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I'm actually using React MUI V5 and basically need to change a `div`'s flex direction from row to column when a previous div changes height or wraps.

Here is a simple example of what I currently have in plain HTML/CSS but unsure if there is another means with flex box to achieve this:

```
      .parent{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }
      .child1{
        display: flex;
        max-width: 80%;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .child2{
        display: flex;
        max-width: 80%;
        height: 30px;
        flex-direction: row;
      }


    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child1">
<p>
      so much data here. so much data here so much data here so much data hereso much data here v so much data here v so much data here vso
      so much data here. so much data here so much data here so much data hereso much data here v so much data here v so much data here vso
      so much data here. so much data here so much data here so much data hereso much data here v so much data here v so much data here vso
      so much data here. so much data here so much data here so much data hereso much data here v so much data here v so much data here vso
   </p>
    
      </div>
      <div class="child2">
        <button>Button1</button>
        <button>Button2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have created a [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Latn7uco/1/) of the above.

Basically, when the div of the class `child1` is a single line (no wrapping or height change) then div class `child2` remains as `flex-direction: row` otherwise this needs to change to `flex-direction: column` when `child1` class wraps or changes height.

Unsure how to achieve this within my MUI component and unsure if I can use MUI V5 breakpoints?

With the jsFiddle example, the flex-direction would need to change to column since `child1` div has wrapped it's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any trace of React or MUI in your code example.
You need to have a state for current height of the first child.
Using a `ref` of first child, we will update the `height` with each render inside `useLayourEffect` in order to have the latest div height.
And I also used MUI `sx props` to apply styles.

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function test() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight);
  });

  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          maxWidth: "80%",
          padding: "10px",
        }}
        ref={ref}
      >
        <p>
          so much data here. so much data here so much data here so much data
          hereso much data here v so much data here v so much data here vso so
          {height}
        </p>
      </Box>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          maxWidth: "80%",
          flexDirection: height < 45 ? "row" : "column",
        }}
      >
        <button>Button1</button>
        <button>Button2</button>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can achieve this with CSS or MUI V5

- You need to use media query or javascript for this

with Javascript, when items wrapped then it's element o̶f̶f̶s̶e̶t̶ offsetheight become greater than 0̶ baseheight and then change flex direction.

```js
function isWrraped(id) {
    let el = document.getElementById(id);
    // 178 is base height
    return (el.offsetHeight > 178);
}

window.onresize = function (event) {
   isWrraped("child1");
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. Are you able to please provide an example re: element offset calculation?

Comment: You're welcome updated with offset calculation